# Mapping paths in remote server (AWS)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, frontend, backend

My colleague has uploaded several front-end projects (react.js) and a back-end (node.js) to AWS.

The path to each project contained many useless sub-directories - 
This is how it used to be :

```
'/home/ubuntu/dir1/dir2/dir3/frontEndProject/src/index.js'
'/home/ubuntu/dir1/dir2/dir3/backEndProject/src/index.js'
'/home/ubuntu/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/frontEndProject2/src/index.js'
```

So I did a little clean-up using Filezilla and made a single main directory where all the front-end projects are currently stored.
The paths now look like this:

```
'/home/ubuntu/main/frontEndProject/src/index.js'
'/home/ubuntu/main/frontEndProject2/src/index.js'
'/home/ubuntu/main/backEndProject/src/index.js'
```

The colleague provided me with links to each of the projects - 
e.g :

`http://123.123.123.123:3000/login` for `frontEndProject`

`http://123.123.123.123:4000/login` for `frontEndProject2`

`http://123.123.123.123:5000/` for `backEndProject`

The issue is I can no longer access those links since I restructured the folders' hierarchy. I can only access the back-end link.

The other links issue errors -

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/ubuntu/dir1/dir2/dir3/frontEndProject/src/index.js'` when trying to access the first link and

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/ubuntu/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/frontEndProject2/src/index.js'` when trying to access the second.

How can I solve this issue? Does it have anything to do with mapping the links to the current path?

Comment: make sure you update  the root file path in your web server config accordingly.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?